# NAnt/Ant file pattern to match filenames with more than 1 dot/period in them

Tags: ant, nant

I want to include all *.dll files from the \bin directory, so I have this:

```
<fileset basedir="${sourcedir}">
  <include name="bin\*.dll" />
```

That includes `a.dll` and `b.dll`. But it does not include `c.c.dll` or `d.d.d.dll`

Is there a better way than including all possible combinations of dots:

```
<include name="bin\*.dll" />
<include name="bin\*.*.dll" />
<include name="bin\*.*.*.dll" />
```

Works today, but what if tomorrow I have a file called `e.e.e.e.dll`?

My understanding is that `**` is reserved for directory parts of the path, so the following *will not work*:

```
<include name="bin\**.dll" />
```

**Note**: I am using NAnt and am running it on Windows. The scenario is I am using the ASP.NET precompiler to precompile aspx/ascx pages for a static scan. That's essentially the situation I have to handle in the NAnt file, so moving to non-windows or renaming the files is a no-go.

Answer (score 0):

I realized later that I was pointing my  basedir attribute to the wrong directory, which did not have files like c.c.dll.  In fact, *.dll does cover all files with the dll extension, including a.dll, b.b.dll, c.c.c.dll, etc..